# HTML - Viewport tag is ignored

Tags: html, viewport

I am trying to optimize my webpage http://boskobence.atw.hu for mobile. I have inserted the viewport tag

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

which everyone suggests, but **nothing changes whether its in or not**. I guess it should zoom in, so fonts would be readable. Furthermore, if i set the content unscalable in the tag, it is still scalable, therefore the tag seem to be ignored compeletely. What am i doing wrong?

**OS**: Android Lollipop

**Browser**: Chrome

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page is actually injected into an `iframe` on the page, either by choice or by your server host. Because there's an ad on the top of the page I'd guess this has been injected in by your host. Your page is essentially being loaded into a sandbox and can't interact with anything outside of it.

Because of this, any meta `viewport` tag you place in your page will be ignored by the browser, even if it's parent doesn't specify it's own `viewport` tag.

Sorry to break the bad news! ;(